# Issue with handling json api response in Python

Tags: python, json

I am using the Censys api in python to programmatically look through host and grab information about them. Censys website says it returns Json formatted data and it looks like Json formatted data but, I cant seem to figure out how to tun the api response into a json object. However, if i write the json response to a json file and load it. It works fine Any ideas?

Update: Figured out issue is with nested json that the api returns. Looking for libraries to flatten it.

Main.py

```
c = censys.ipv4.CensysIPv4(api_id=UID, api_secret=SECRET)
for result in c.search("autonomous_system.asn:15169 AND tags.raw:iot", max_records=1):

 hostIPS.append(result["ip"]);

for host in hostIPS:

  for details in c.view(host):
    # test = json.dumps(details)
    # test = json.load(test)
    # data = json.load(details)
    data = json.loads(details)
    print(data)
```

Comment: What is c? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it to an object, it's already `json.loaded`. See the implementation here: https://github.com/censys/censys-python/blob/master/censys/base.py